# Functions.php file in a custom child theme messed up without backup

Tags: php, functions

I just ran into some problem. I'm a beginning Wordpress dev. I don't know much and I have messed up my functions.php file. Here's how it happened: I copied the code from [This site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/). This was supposed to target all posts of a specific category and change their template. It should have worked well but instead of pasting the code below the functions, I accidentally pasted it over some lines of code..So I got a parse file error and I had to use FTP to access it. I deleted all the code that I had copied before and am left with an incomplete functions.php file.
I don't know what to do now. Can anyone be kind enough to help me? Here is the code that's left in the functions.php:

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

/**
*
* WARNING: Please do not edit this file in any way
*
* load the theme function files
*/
require ( get_template_directory() . '/core/includes/functions.php' );
require ( get_template_directory() . '/core/includes/theme-options.php' );
require ( get_template_directory() . '/core/includes/post-custom-meta.php'   );
require ( get_template_directory() . '/core/includes/tha-theme-hooks.php' );
?>
```

There is a php starting tag above this but for some reason, I'm not able to display it in here...I also tried to put a closing php tag below the code but it isn't solving the problem.

Comment: Hi, @StoryMode, and welcome to WPSE. First of all, delete that `endforeach;` and check if it works.

Comment: check the parent theme for an example child theme functions.php it may show you what is missing

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, the problem was solved. I looked more in the FTP and found a little readme.txt. The file had the name of the theme which was modified and made into a child theme. I googled it, downloaded it and got the functions.php. I still got a few errors but I just removed the lines that were causing the errors and now the site is working! Thanks everyone!